# Подсчёт количества секций в Fullpage.js (current/ total)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет. Использую скрипт Fullpage.js для создания презентации. Как выводить номер активного слайда и общее количество слайдов с фиксированном `div`'е?

*Вид структуры:*

```
<div id="myContainer">
 <div class="section"></div>
 <div class="section"></div>
 <div class="section"></div>
 <div class="section"></div>
 <div class="section"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте для этого `callback`-функции:

```js
$('#myContainer').fullpage({
  sectionsColor: ['#f2f2f2', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', 'whitesmoke', 'yellow'],
  afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) { // при загрузке
    var total = $('#myContainer').find('.fp-section').length;
    $('.out-current').text(index);
    $('.out-total').text(total);
  },
  onLeave: function(anchorLink, index) { // при переходе на другой слайд
    $('.out-current').text(index);
  }
});
```

```css
.output {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.4/jquery.fullpage.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullPage.js/2.9.4/jquery.fullpage.js"></script>
<div id="myContainer">
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
  <div class="section"></div>
</div>
<div class="output">
  <span class="out-current"></span> слайд из <span class="out-total"></span>
</div>
```

Подробнее читайте в [документации](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#callbacks).